# How do I dynamically update a Maps Engine data table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-engine

I have a Maps Engine  map with one of the layers linked to a data table containing a single location.  I would like to update the data table via JavaScript in Google Sites. The [`mapsengine.tables.features.batchPatch`](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/mapsengine/v1/mapsengine.tables.features.batchPatch) seems to do what I want, and the help page for the `batchInsert` version of the same command seems like it could be modified to do what I want.  However, I'm having difficulty getting it to work properly.  I believe the problem is due to the fact that I don't know what the primary key is for this table or where I can find it (see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/feature-update#errors) for more explanation).

Can anyone here tell me if I'm headed in the right direction, and how I might be able to find this primary key (it also seems to be referred to as a `gx_id` at times)?  Thanks in advance for whatever help you may be able to provide.

**Edit:** When I go [here](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/mapsengine/v1/mapsengine.tables.list?_h=1&) and get the information on my table, I get the following response:

```
{
 "tables": [
  {
   "id": {My Table ID},
   "etag": "\"6030101253664097613\"",
   "projectId": {My Project ID},
   "name": "Current Location",
   "description": "",
   "tags": [
   ],
   "writersCanEditPermissions": false,
   "sourceEncoding": "UTF-8",
   "processingStatus": "complete",
   "bbox": [
    -180,
    -90,
    180,
    90
   ],
   "creationTime": "2014-11-11T21:33:43.982Z",
   "lastModifiedTime": "2014-11-12T20:55:20.613Z"
  }
 ]
}
```

As you can see, there is no `gx_id` listed.  Is there some way to add it, or do I need to recreate the table to be able to add it from the start?  If I need to recreate the table, what do I need to do to make sure the `gx_id` is there, since it wasn't immediately apparent when I created the table last time that anything was missing.

Comment: tried what have you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine.  You can find your `gx_id` simply by fetching a copy of your table and checking the properties.  Here's a sample [from the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/public-read):

Request:

> https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/12421761926155747447-06672618218968397709/features?maxResults=500&version=published&key=(YOUR_KEY_HERE)

Response:

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
  {
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     149.23531999999997,
     -35.352484
    ]
   },
   "properties": {
    ...
    "gx_id": "1" <-- HERE
   }
  },
```

Comment: Using your link, I got a "bad request" response (even after replacing both the table's key and the project key with the correct information. I was able to find what your referring to [here](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/mapsengine/v1/mapsengine.tables.list?_h=1&).  I will update the original question with the results.

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/errors#error_reasons.  In particular, is your table public?  If not, you'll need to use OAuth to access it: https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/oauth/#oauth_20_flows

Comment: That's not the problem. If you look at the edited post, you'll see that I can get the API to return information, so it's not an authorization problem. The problem is I don't know how to get or set the `gx_id` for this table.

Comment: That's the wrong API call.  `tables.list` gives you a list of tables; you need to call `tables.features`, which gives you the list of features in your table, including the gx_ids.

Comment: That was the solution!  Thanks!